# Python + Iterator resulting from map sharing current state with the initial iterator

Tags: python, iterator

Let me illustrate this with an example we came across with my students :

```py
>>>a_lot = (i for i in range(10e50))
>>>twice_a_lot = map(lambda x: 2*x, a_lot)
>>>next(a_lot)
0
>>>next(a_lot)
1
>>>next(a_lot)
2
>>>next(twice_a_lot)
6
```

So somehow these iterators share their current state, as crazy and unconfortable as it sounds...
Any hints as of the model python uses behind the scene ?

Comment: `map()` evaluates lazily. So each time you evaluate the next item it calls `next()` on `a_lot`. The result is that calling `next(twice_a_lot)` calls `next(a_lot)` in order to get the next value to pass to its function. In general iterators can only produce a given sequence once. You can pass them around, but it's like sharing a pez dispenser — you can't eat the same candy and share it too.

Comment: You are using the same generator `a_lot` in both., of course it is shared.

Comment: BTW, if `map` was not lazy, then it would consume the complete `a_lot` and `next(a_lot)` would fail.

Comment: This isn't crazy at all. How else could this possibly work? When you call `iter` on an iterator, it returns itself.

Comment: so could I get an iterator2 computed from an iterator1 ()through a map(...) BUT independent in the way I walk them through with next... Should I .copy() something ? Ok, i get it, start fresh from the initial formula, don't compose...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I never said it was crazy, I was just surprised the first time I saw it...

Comment: By the way, `range(10e50)` isn't valid, as `range` can't take a `float` argument.

Comment: ok, i owe you a `range(int(10e50))`. The original idea was `range(10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)`, like do not `list(map(lambda x:2*x, a_lot))`, no don't, you don't want that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be surprising at first but upon a little reflection, it should seem obvious.

When you create an iterator from another iterator, there is no way to recover the original state over whatever underlying container you are iterating over (in this case, the `range` object). At least not in general.

Consider the simplest case of this: `iter(something)`.

When `something` is an iterator, then according to the [iterator protocol specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), `iterator.__iter__` must:

> Return the iterator object itself

In other words, if you've implemented the protocol correctly, then the following identity will always hold:

```
iter(iterator) is iterator
```

Of course, `map` could have some convention that would allow it to recover and create an *independent* iterator, but there is no such convention. In general, if you want to create independent iterators, you need to create it from the source.

And of course, there are iterators where this really is not possible without storing all previous results. Consider:

```
import random

def random_iterator():
    while True:
        yield random.random()
```

In which case, how should map function with the following?

```
iterator = random_iterator()
twice = map(lambda x: x*2, iterator)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thx to all the comments received (in less than 5 minutes!!!!) i understood to related things : if I want two independent iterators, I won't use map to compute the snd from the fst :

```
>>>a_lot = (i for i in range(10e50))
>>>twice_a_lot = (2*i for i in range(10e50))
```

and i'll remember `map` is lazy,'cause there's no other way that could make sense.
That was a nice `SO` lesson.

THX

Comment: You can also use `itertools.tee`, if for whatever reason you can't hard-code the definition of the iterate twice: `a_lot, tmp = tee(range(10**50)); twice_a_lot = (2*i for i in tmp)`. The drawback is that values pulled from one iterator need to be cached until the other iterator catches up.